matching up DNS A and PTR records
If you have a minute, I am a little confused about addressing rDNS warning for outbound emails. I have this setup...
http web server (ip 1.2.3.4, hostname apps.acme.com)
smtp mail server (ip 1.2.3.5, hostname mail.acme.com)

DNS A record (Domain name = acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.4) --> web server
PTR record (Domain name = acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.5) --> smtp server

The smtp server only sends mail, no inbounds, no MX record, etc.
However, when I check mail reputation score, I see rDNS warning and found that PTR records should have corresponding A record (forward-confirmed). However, if I create a second DNS A record for the smtp server...
DNS A record (Domain name = acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.5) --> smtp server

Won't this mean that the authoritative server will direct some acme.com DNS resolution traffic to the smtp server? thank you very much for reading this.

Yes, it would, at least for traffic other than that destined for apps.acme.com. So rather than DNS A record (Domain name = acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.5), what you do is make DNS PTR record (ip = 1.2.3.5, domain = mail.acme.com). You may still want a PTR record for acme.com, of course, but you apply that to ip = 1.2.3.4 which is where you're sending all that traffic anyway.
EDIT: Since the comments have gotten incredibly unwieldy, with information that should have properly gone in the initial question, I'll toss all of that in here as well.
Given that the SMTP server mail.acme.com does in fact receive mail (destined for specific addresses, directed there by the principal mail server acme.mail.protection.outlook.com, and from certain web apps), we do need to have an active MTA on mail.acme.com which means that if there is an MX record, no matter what priority we set of the record, some mail will erroneously get sent to mail.acme.com. (This will happen when the primary is not responding, by design, and I'll note in passing that spammers pay no attention to MX priority, firing messages at any MX they find.) So the first step in the process is to add a firewall that is set to reject any connection to the MTA except from the primary and the hosts where the web apps run.
Once that's done, we can create three records in DNS as follows:
A mail.acme.com 1.2.3.5
PTR 1.2.3.5 mail.acme.com
MX acme.com mail.acme.com priority 50

Traffic for acme.com still resolves to 1.2.3.4 as before; the only traffic that ends up going to mail.acme.com is mail, and that's blocked by the firewall unless it's from the primary or the web apps. As far as I can see there's no need for an A record for acme.com at 1.2.3.5, as that one is set to resolve both forward and back to mail.acme.com, and the MX record provides the link that shows this is an MX for the domain.

thanks so much, yeah, I originally had that setup using the smtp server hostname as the domain to match A and PTR...
DNS A record (Domain name = mail.acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.5) and
PTR record (Domain name = mail.acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.5)
but that was when I first noticed the rDNS warning. I think it's because the recipient server is using the domain in the header From (wilecoyote@acme.com)... not the Return-Path server stuff... leaving the acme.com <> mail.acme.com domain discrepancy.

I suppose the canonical answer to this would be to use a single IP address for everything, and redirect to specific machines via port mapping somewhere. But assuming that's not an option, have you considered putting in a DNS MX record (domain = acme.com, mailserver = mail.acme.com, priority = 50)? That might make the connection that rDNS is looking for.

yeah, i t's a weird setup. This isn't the primary smtp server for the acme.com domain (different ip) which has an MX record and its own load balancing As behind it. The primary handles all the main two-way traffic. The mail.acme.com is outbound only in support of a couple apps on the network, a couple of bulk subscription stuff. I think putting an MX out there will draw inbound mail which it can't deal with.

That's why I set the priority value so high... says to use the other first. And even if it does attract some mail traffic, if your MTA is not active on 1.2.3.5, a real mailer will try on the other one. May need to use a firewall to block that port to outside while leaving it active for internal hosts.

mail.acme.com, although sending outbounds directly to internet, technically receives inbounds from the primary domain mail server. (Exchange). I'm not sure how this is   accomplished on their end (primary mail server), I was presuming Exchange has connectors to route mail. But I am thinking the MTA needs to be running for this, does that sound right?

So the primary mail server drops (at least some) mail on mail.acme.com once it has been handled? Yes, you'll need an MTA for that. So the firewall becomes necessary; it would allow inbound SMTP traffic from the web apps and from the primary. Anything else that happens to try to reach mail.acme.com from the broader Internet would get  connection denied and try the primary.

yes, right, all inbounds go to the primary (acme.mail.protection.outlook.com) which drops a small subset of emails bound for a particular set of acme.com addresses (wilecoyote@acme.com, plapew@acme.com) on mail.acme.com. I'll have to look at whitelisting more, but would the same domain (@acme.com) situation occur with whitelisting at the firewall or within the smtp server software?...or could I use the primary mail server hostname (acme.mail.protection.outlook.com)?

You'd use the primary mail server hostname or IP at the firewall, along with any IPs used by the web apps that mail through mail.acme.com. The firewall would grant SMTP / MTA access to those, and deny to everywhere else on the net.

Ok, thanks do much. Going back through the thread, I can create second MX record for mail.acme.com, priority=50, whitelist on firewall to allow primary smtp and app hostnames/ips...but the new mail MX for mail.acme.com needs the new A behind it (domain = acme.com, ip = 1.2.3.5...this is mail.acme.com ip). How did we say to keep DNS resolved web traffic from hitting tjis smtp server rather than the web server with acme.com domain?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
